# Convert file to base string in php

Tags: php, data-stream

I saw many questions saying how to convert image into base 64 but i need how to convert any format file into stream like `"3C3F786D6C2076657273696F6E3D22312E302220656E636F64696E673D225554462D38223F3E3C69646D65663A49444D45462D4D65737361676520786D6C6E733A69646........."`

In php

Comment: [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)?

Comment: but it wont convert the file into those "3C3F786D6C2076657273696F6E3D22312E302220656E636F64696E673D225554462D38223F3E3C69646D65663A49444D45462D4D65737361676520786D6C6E733A69646........."